# canvas tile grid with hover effects, tilesheet, etc

Tags: javascript, html, sprite, html5-canvas

I've been working on building a tile-based display grid for canvas.  This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/dDmTf/7/

Some problems I'm having, and can't quite grasp are:

1. <strike>The initial load time is ridiculous... I don't understand what I'm doing wrong</strike> - fixed, found out I was rendering ^32 more than I was supposed to
2. The hover effect, which "should" just highlight the border of the tile, erases it, and I have no way of recovering the previous tile without re-rendering the entire canvas.
3. <strike>How do I use tilesheets, providing me a single image instead of a bunch of small ones</strike>
4. <strike>Resizing the window (which resizes the canvas) also erases the canvas. Do I need to re-render? Or can I maintain state of various things when width/height is changed</strike> - added an `onresize` callback, which re-renders the map. Might not be the best way though?
5. Multiple layers? How would I go about allowing transparency .png files overlaying each-other

Those are the main problems I'm stuck on right now, and any guidance would be majorly appreciated.

Also, if you have any pointers for my javascript, feel free! I'm learning it more as I go, and I'm sure I'm doing a lot of things wrong.

#### Edit

As an FYI, I just copy-pasted the sprite map currently being shown on the jsfiddle. It's not the one I'm planning to use, but it was easier than uploading one. I plan to maintain a 32x32 grid instead of (what appears to be) a 16x16 grid from that tilesheet

#### Edit

I've got the a 32x32 tilesheet displaying on there now, but the hover effect is still breaking it, and I'm not sure how to "know" what the old value was.

Comment: you might want to start from adding `drawTile` to your redraw logic ;)

Comment: But how would it know the tile?

Comment: dude, there is too much code to play with, sorry. Take your time, set up quite workplace, get some tea or coffee. And in a hour or two you will fix this on your own, and receive a reason to be proud of yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not redrawing your tiles after 'mouseout'.
You either need to redraw the single tile after you move out of it, but this can get tricky as things get more complicated or better yet on mouse move do the following.

- Clear the canvas
- draw the grid
- draw your tiles
- then do the highlighting/clearing that cell.

If you end up having any sort of animation this is the process that will be used anyhow otherwise as something moves from one tile to another it will leave ghost images behind.